# How to find cause for iTunes not exporting library XML?

Tags: itunes, macos, xml

My iTunes XML export has not been working for months but I need it for DJ software like Traktor Pro. 
I would like to find and fix the problem and can't reset the database.

When trying to export the whole library as XML manually (File -> Library -> Export Library) I can see `Assertion failure: success == noErr (-8753)` in the system log but that is ALL I know right now.

**What can I do find the root cause of this problem?**

macOS version: 10.12.5
iTunes version: 12.6.1.25

These are my relevant settings:
[image]

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen these libraries get a bit corrupted many times even though they'll still work perfectly in iTunes.

I think that's probably what's going on here so I don't have a lot of faith in my first three suggestions but they're a lot less dangerous / serious & could definitely fix the issue. The 'nuclear' option I've listed last is safe to do but it involves rebuilding your entire iTunes database which if you're a DJ might be more than you'd like to jump to. If you have backups though it will always be fine to take the riskier route first.

1. Just in case you haven't tried, uncheck 'Share iTunes Library XML with other applications' hit ok, open up preferences and check it again. Try to export.
2. We can test this on a clean slate with a new user. Copy (move if there's not enough space) the entire iTunes folder over to the [shared area of your computer](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21829?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US), and then create a new administrator over in System Preferences > Users & Groups. Restart & log in to that one, add your iTunes library by selecting it in the same advanced tab of iTunes preferences shown in your screenshot. This might take a little bit of time. Then try out an export.
3. If that still doesn't work, the last thing I would recommend to try is to replace the 'System' folder where iTunes & other system functions are kept in case there's an issue there. You can do this by booting into recovery mode by holding CMD + R while the Mac is starting, and install onto your disk. This won't affect your data or users at all - in only replaces the System folder where OS stuff only is at.

When none of those work take the nuclear option and rebuild your iTunes library using [these instructions](http://www.kirkville.com/how-to-rebuild-your-itunes-library/). Backing up before this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find the root cause of this problem by evaluating whether or not the "**iTunes Music Library.xml**" file has a valid syntax using `xmllint`. For example, a Terminal command like the following may point out where any corruption exists inside of that XML file:

`xmllint --valid --noout ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music\ Library.xml`

If the command executes without any complaints, then the file's syntax is probably OK. Alternately, if `xmllint` points out that the file has an invalid XML syntax, it should specify which line or tag the error exists within. It may be possible to correct those errors by hand if you're familiar with XML structure/syntax (but it's probably a good idea to perform a backup of the file before modifying it).

Comment: The file is not created at all so I cannot validate the file.

Comment: @Hedge - I'm recommending that you validate the _existing_ **iTunes Music Library.xml** file, not the one that you're attempting to export. That file should definitely exist inside of the location that you store your iTunes music library. For example: if your iTunes library is stored in the default location (~/Music/iTunes), then the path above should be correct. If you store your iTunes library directly inside of a drive called "Storage", the path to the library's XML file might be something like "/Volumes/Storage/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml".

Comment: @EddieKelley iTunes by default doesn't make an xml anymore :~(